# How to make Excel macro splitting file into several in silent mode?

Tags: vba, excel

For splitting a file into several files by unique names in certain column I used a wonderful VBA snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23113062/2938167).

I've added some code to achieve required functionality like replacing `.SpecialCells` to `.EntireRow` and adding multiple filters to meet all possible cases in that task of splitting.

However, I've found that after linking this snippet to UserForm via button, Excel's starting blinking and filtering as the snippet works in real time. I have to split an Excel file into several hundreds, and it is rather complicated task in terms of PC's perfomance.

The question is "Are there any VBA or Excel settings to run VBA snippets silently without GUI events?". I hope the nature of my question is clear.

Comment: `application.screenupdating=false`

Comment: Indeed, application.screenupdating=false is the way to go

Comment: @findwindow thank you!

Comment: remember to add `application.screenupdating=true` at the end. Or your excel will seem dead.

Comment: @Aganju - `Screenupdating` is automatically reset as soon as your code is done executing...

Comment: just as a note - its not silent,   that instance of excel will still hang while its running and will not be usable until the code is complete.

Comment: OT: You may want to read to [this](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/ten-things-you-can-do-to-speed-up-your-excel-vba-code/) or [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm) to understand how to speed up code in Excel and avoid some events