# Splitting excel workbook with multiple worksheets with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to split my workbook with multiple worksheets' data according to each worksheets' team column, I wrote something like this based on this [Split file into multiple files in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106555/split-file-into-multiple-files-in-excel)

But I can't get the copy filter filterrange 2 to new workbook worksheet 2 part work, I keep getting "runtime error 424".

```vb
Sub Splitting()

Dim OutBook As Workbook
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, OutSheet As Worksheet
Dim FilterRange As Range
Dim UniqueNames  As New Collection

Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, _
    TeamCol As Long, tIndex As Long, kIndex As Long
Dim OutName As String

'set references and variables up-front for ease-of-use
'Comm_Sum

Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Comm_Sum")

TeamCol = 4
LastRow = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastCol = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
Set FilterRange = Range(DataSheet.Cells(1, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

'loop through the name column and store unique names in a collection
For tIndex = 2 To LastRow
    On Error Resume Next
        UniqueNames.Add Item:=DataSheet.Cells(tIndex, TeamCol), Key:=DataSheet.Cells(tIndex, TeamCol)
    On Error GoTo 0
Next tIndex

' KPI
Dim DataSheet2 As Worksheet
Dim kTeamCol As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long, LastCol2 As Long
Dim FilterRange2 As Range

Set DataSheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KPI")

kTeamCol = 4
LastRow2 = DataSheet2.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastCol2 = DataSheet2.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
Set FilterRange2 = Range(DataSheet2.Cells(3, 1), DataSheet2.Cells(LastRow2, LastCol2))

'loop through the name column and store unique names in a collection
'Comm_Sum
Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Comm_Sum")

For tIndex = 2 To LastRow
    On Error Resume Next
        UniqueNames.Add Item:=DataSheet.Cells(tIndex, TeamCol), Key:=DataSheet.Cells(tIndex, TeamCol)
    On Error GoTo 0
Next tIndex

'KPI

Set DataSheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KPI")

For kIndex = 4 To LastRow2
    On Error Resume Next
        UniqueNames2.Add Item:=DataSheet2.Cells(kIndex, kTeamCol), Key:=DataSheet2.Cells(tIndex, kTeamCol)
    On Error GoTo 0
Next kIndex

'iterate through the unique names collection, writing
'to new workbooks and saving as the group name .xls
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
' Comm_Sum
For tIndex = 1 To UniqueNames.Count
    Set OutBook = Workbooks.Add
    Set OutSheet = OutBook.Sheets(1)
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    Set OutSheet2 = OutBook.Sheets(2)
    With FilterRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=TeamCol, Criteria1:=UniqueNames(tIndex)
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy OutSheet.Range("A1")

    End With
Next tIndex

' KPI
For kIndex = 4 To UniqueNames2.Count
    Set OutSheet2 = OutBook.Sheets(2)
    With FilterRange2
        .AutoFilter Field:=TeamCol2, Criteria1:=UniqueNames2(kIndex)
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy OutSheet2.Range("A1")

End With
Next kIndex

' Name
oWBName = ThisWorkbook.FullName

If InStr(oWBName, ".") > 0 Then
   oWBName = Left(oWBName, InStr(oWBName, ".") - 1)
End If
   
    OutName = oWBName & UniqueNames(tIndex)
    OutBook.SaveAs Filename:=OutName, FileFormat:=xlExcel8
    OutBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Call ClearAllFilters(DataSheet)

Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub

'safely clear all the filters on data sheet
'safely clear all the filters on data sheet
Sub ClearAllFilters(TargetSheet As Worksheet)
    With TargetSheet
        TargetSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        If .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Split workbook with multiple worksheets according to team, copy all of them to new workbook's corresponding worksheets.

**26/2/2024 Update:
Just find a way to make this work**

```
Sub Split()
Dim Team(100) As String
Dim Alias(100) As String
Dim TeamMail(100) As String
Dim xTeam As String

Dim OutBook As Workbook
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, OutSheet As Worksheet
Dim FilterRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, _
NameCol As Long, Index As Long
Dim OutName As String
Dim Savepath As String

* Set references and variables up-front for ease-of-use
Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Comm_Sum" )
Set DataSheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KPI")

Savepath = "C:\Users\XXX\XXX\XXX\"

* Range 1

NameCol = 4

LastRow = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=x1ByRows,
SearchDirection:=x1Previous ) .Row

LastCol = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=x1ByColumns,
SearchDirection:=x1Previous).Column
Set FilterRange = Range(DataSheet.Cells(1, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

* Range 2

NameCol2 = 2

LastRow2 = DataSheet2.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=x1ByRows,
SearchDirection:=x1Previous) .Row

LastCol2 = DataSheet2.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=x1ByColumns,
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

Set FilterRange2 = Range(DataSheet2.Cells(2, 1), DataSheet2.Cells(LastRow2,
LastCol2))

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Team(1) = "John Smith"
Team(2) = "Jenny Smith"

* For Loop

For i = 1 To 2
xTeam = Team(i)


Set OutBook = Workbooks.Add
OutBook.Worksheets.Add
Set OutSheet = OutBook.Sheets(1)
Set OutSheet2 = OutBook.Sheets(2)

* Worksheet 1 
With FilterRange
-AutoFilter Field:=NameCol, Criterial:=xTeam

.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy OutSheet.Range("A1")
End With

* Worksheet 2
With FilterRange2
.AutoFilter Field:=NameCol2, Criterial:=xTeam
.Specialcells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy OutSheet2.Range("A1")
End With

OutName = xTeam & ".xlsx"

OutBook.SaveAs Filename:=Savepath & OutName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
OutBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Call ClearAllFilters(DataSheet)

Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Sub ClearAllFilters(TargetSheet As Worksheet)
With TargetSheet
TargetSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
If .FilterMode Then
. ShowAllData
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- It is highly recommended to include `Option Explicit` in all VBA modules. Many coding errors can be detected when you compile the VBA project.
- `TeamCol2` should be `kTeamCol`

```vb
    ' KPI
    For kIndex = 4 To UniqueNames2.Count
        Set OutSheet2 = OutBook.Sheets(2)
        With FilterRange2
            .AutoFilter Field:=TeamCol2, Criteria1:=UniqueNames2(kIndex) ' **
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy OutSheet2.Range("A1")
        End With
    Next kIndex
```

- Although the code can run without following variable declaration, it is not recommended.

```vb
Dim UniqueNames2 As New Collection, OutSheet2 As Worksheet, oWBName As String ' **
```

---

*Update:*

- Get unique names list with Dictionary object instead of collection. It is easier the check the existance of name.
- For each name, copy related data from Comm_Sum and KPI, then save it as a new workbook.
- Add a snippet to handle if the unique names are in KPI, but not in Comm_Sum
- *Note:* The code isn't tested coz of lacking sample data.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Splitting()
    Dim OutBook As Workbook, OutFileName As String
    Dim OutWBName As String, vKey
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet, OutSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, TeamCol As Long, iIndex As Long
    Dim FilterRange As Range
    Dim UniqueDict1  As Object
    Set UniqueDict1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'Comm_Sum
    Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Comm_Sum")
    TeamCol = 4
    LastRow = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastCol = DataSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Set FilterRange = DataSheet.Range(DataSheet.Cells(1, 1), DataSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    'loop through the name column and store unique names in a Dict
    For iIndex = 2 To LastRow
        vKey = DataSheet.Cells(iIndex, TeamCol)
        If Not UniqueDict1.exists(vKey) Then UniqueDict1(vKey) = ""
    Next iIndex
    ' KPI
    Dim DataSheet2 As Worksheet, OutSheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow2 As Long, LastCol2 As Long, kTeamCol As Long
    Dim FilterRange2 As Range, c As Range
    Dim UniqueDict2 As Object
    Set UniqueDict2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set DataSheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KPI")
    kTeamCol = 4
    LastRow2 = DataSheet2.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastCol2 = DataSheet2.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Set FilterRange2 = DataSheet2.Range(DataSheet2.Cells(3, 1), DataSheet2.Cells(LastRow2, LastCol2))
    'loop through the name column and store unique names in a Dict
    'KPI
    Set DataSheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("KPI")
    For iIndex = 4 To LastRow2
        vKey = DataSheet2.Cells(iIndex, kTeamCol)
        If Not UniqueDict2.exists(vKey) Then UniqueDict2(vKey) = ""
    Next iIndex
    'iterate through the unique names collection, writing
    'to new workbooks and saving as the group name .xls
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ' Name
    Const DIR_PATH = "C:\DATA\"  ' Modify as needed
    Const FILE_EXT = ".xls"
    OutWBName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    If InStr(OutWBName, ".") > 0 Then
        OutWBName = Left(OutWBName, InStr(OutWBName, ".") - 1) & "-"
    Else
        OutWBName = "C:\DATA\" & OutWBName & "-"
    End If
    ' unique names are in Comm_Sum
    For Each vKey In UniqueDict1
        Set OutBook = Workbooks.Add
        Set OutSheet = OutBook.Sheets(1)
        With FilterRange
            .AutoFilter Field:=TeamCol, Criteria1:=vKey
            Set c = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then c.Copy OutSheet.Range("A1")
        End With
        ' Check if the name is exist in KPI
        If UniqueDict2.exists(vKey) Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
            Set OutSheet2 = OutBook.Sheets(2)
            With FilterRange2
                .AutoFilter Field:=kTeamCol, Criteria1:=vKey
                Set c = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                If Not c Is Nothing Then c.Copy OutSheet2.Range("A1")
            End With
        End If
        OutFileName = OutWBName & vKey & FILE_EXT
        OutBook.SaveAs Filename:=OutFileName, FileFormat:=xlExcel8
        OutBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next vKey
    '  unique names are in KPI, but not in Comm_Sum
    For Each vKey In UniqueDict2
        If Not UniqueDict1.exists(vKey) Then
            Set OutBook = Workbooks.Add
            Set OutSheet2 = OutBook.Sheets(1)
            With FilterRange2
                .AutoFilter Field:=kTeamCol, Criteria1:=vKey
                Set c = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                If Not c Is Nothing Then c.Copy OutSheet2.Range("A1")
            End With
            OutFileName = OutWBName & vKey & FILE_EXT
            OutBook.SaveAs Filename:=OutFileName, FileFormat:=xlExcel8
            OutBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    Next
    Call ClearAllFilters(DataSheet)
    Call ClearAllFilters(DataSheet2)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

'safely clear all the filters on data sheet
Sub ClearAllFilters(TargetSheet As Worksheet)
    With TargetSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        If .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I find that my code end up creating a dozen separate workbook with two worksheets in the end, each with data copy from the original workbook, instead of creating workbooks with a two worksheets filter by team name as I intended.

Comment: I've updated the reply to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it still doesn't work it just copy both worksheets' data to a single sheet in new work book and end in error. It's there a better way to do this? The "team head" in "Comm_Sum" and "Agent Team" in "KPI" suppose to contains same sales head name, can I create a mapping worksheet then tell vba to copy all entries with same sales head to new work book?

Comment: I've refactored the code based on your comments. If the code doesn't meet your expectations, please provide sample data and the expected output in your post.